# How to double the size of 8x8 Grid whilst keeping the relative position of certain tiles intact?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have grid size of size 8x8 , total of 64 Tiles.

I'm using this grid to implement java search algorithms such as BFS and DFS.

The Grid has given forbidden Tiles (meaning they can't be traversed or be neighbour of any other tile) as well as a Goal and a Start tile. for example Tile `19,20,21,22 and 35, 52`  are forbidden and  `14 an 43` are the `Goal` and `start` Tile when the program runs.

My question is , How can i double the size of the grid, to `16x16` whilst keeping the `Relative position of forbidden tiles` as well as the `Relative position of start and goal Tiles` intact?

By simply Declaring an array of `grid[16][16]` the forbidden tiles and the Goal and start tiles are no longer in relative positions as they were in grid size 8x8.

On paper i know i can do this by adding `4 rows and columns to all sides` but in coding terms i don't know how to make it work? Can someone please give any sort of hints?

Comment: It is very unclear what exactly it is that you want. Could you supply a before and after drawing perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not resizable in Java, what you need to do is allocate a new array with the required dimension and copy your data to it.

For instance if you want the old map to be at the center of the new one:

```
Tile[][] newMap = new Tile[16][16];

for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
  for (int j=0; j<8; j++) 
    newMap[i+4][j+4] = oldMap[i][j];
```

But you'd still have to initialize the other tiles to something else.

Comment: yes my current Grid is declared using a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Guillaume.

It's not that i want old map to be at the centre of the new map. I'm more concerned with the relative position of the Tiles when moving from size 8x8 to size 16x16.

For example , if grid size is 8x8, if the Goal tile is 19 and Start tile is 44, in the new 16x16 grid the Goal tile should be 103 and Start tile should be 152 (conforming to the idea of adding 4 rows and columns to each side of grid).

Comment: I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be by using a tile numbering scheme. You'll be better served by naming your tiles according to their 2d coordinates.

Comment: i agree but this is the requirement for what i am trying to archive, because whilst i can implement the search algorithms however i wish, the requirements for the gird, specifically the starting tile position and goal tile position and the forbidden tiles on grid regardless of whether it is size 8x8 or 16x16 cannot be changed as the position of the tiles will affect the result of the ultimately implemented search algorithms . I'm desperately looking to find a way pass this.

Comment: I've got to say I'm confused, I'm not even sure to understand what you want to do. Could you send an example showing how the tiles are placed on a 8x8 grid and on a 16x16 grid?

Answer (score 0):

Something simple could be to put the element at (i,j) in the old grid at (2i, 2j) in the new one... the relative positions of tiles would be kept...

Comment: How can that be? In the original grid size 8x8 for example tile 19 is at i(2) j(2) (0 based array). How can 2i,2j be relative to that in grid 16x16? Can you be more detailed please? I'm sorry i just don't see it.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you're question. what i propose is a solution to have a scale of the grid by inserting blank elements... But as I read your question again maybe it is not that what you want (is relative position meaning "A is at the right/left of B" or "A is collapsed at right of B", in the second case my answer does not work).

Comment: I'm totally confused myself. I'm taking a break to think about it before confusing you guys any further. Thanks for trying to help though. Much appreciated.